# How to fill values in valid SOAP request xml template

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap, jaxb

I  have Soap-request-"template" which I have created through SOAPUI  with reference of a WSDL-file

Please provide a solution to fill the values in SOAP xml template to call webservice

The  SOAP XML-file looks like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tem:DEAAppSearch>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:UserName>?</tem:UserName>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:Password>?</tem:Password>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:DEA>?</tem:DEA>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:BAC>?</tem:BAC>
      </tem:DEAAppSearch>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Import the `wsdl` and have `eclipse` or whatever ide you are using generate a proxy for you...

Answer (score 1):

In SoapUI go to the File menu, select Preferences. Click on the WSDL button in the left pane and check Sample Values. Next SOAP project will generate sample values. Make sure to check "Create sample request for all operations?" on the "New SOAP Project" dialog. Success.